# Connecting to a sleeping mac via SFTP

Tags: macos, sftp

I'm looking at getting a 5K iMac for the office plus a new MacBook for commuting. Problem is keeping the two in sync, which I plan to do by only taking files with me on the MacBook that I need, and updating the changed files on the iMac when I get home.

But what if I forget something? I figured I'd use SFTP to access the files on my iMac, which will be permanently connected to my home network via ethernet.

My question is regarding this method when my iMac is in sleep (or hibernate) mode - will I still be able to access my files? If not, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why has this been voted down?

Comment: Actually you can use sftp but i've always preferred mounting directly over AFP

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @prodigitalson thanks - this would actually have been my preferred method but didn't realise you could use it for remote access, so I'll check it out.

Comment: Well in all fairness you should only do so with a VPN or over an ssh tunnel... So i suppose there isnt much to be gained there except for not having to deal with a FTP client. Of course if you only need to download you can mount ftp (and im pretty sure sftp) in the finder anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you enable Wake on Lan in the Energy Saver settings you should be fine.  If sFTP doesn't wake the iMac up, SSH access will. Basic instructions [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/14/wake-on-lan-mac-iphone/).